# Matplotlib: Can we draw a histogram and a box plot on a same chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, histogram, boxplot

I have a question about drawing a histogram and a box plot Matplotlib.

I know I can draw a histogram and a box plot individually. My question is, is it possible to draw them on the same graph, such as a chart shown in this website? [Springer Images](http://www.springerimages.com/Images/RSS/1-10.1007_s10530-010-9707-x-1)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You should consult [`subplot`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html).  Each subplot need not have their own axes, ticks.

Comment: In addition, you will need to share one of the axes (following your Springer example), and reduce the white space between the subplots. Have a look at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/ganged_plots.html. For the future: there are hundreds of examples at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html, and often one of those gets close to what you want.

Comment: See also [Histogram with Boxplot above in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381330/histogram-with-boxplot-above-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this with matplotlib. The `plt.subplots()` method, and the `AxesGrid1` and `gridspec` toolkits all provide very elegant solutions, but might take time to learn.

A simple, brute-force way to do this would be to manually add the axes objects to a figure yourself.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fake data
x = np.random.lognormal(mean=2.25, sigma=0.75, size=37)

# setup the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
bpAx = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2])   # left, bottom, width, height:
                                            # (adjust as necessary)
histAx = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5]) # left specs should match and
                                            # bottom + height on this line should
                                            # equal bottom on bpAx line
# plot stuff
bp = bpAx.boxplot(x, notch=True, vert=False)
h = histAx.hist(x, bins=7)

# confirm that the axes line up 
xlims = np.array([bpAx.get_xlim(), histAx.get_xlim()])
for ax in [bpAx, histAx]:
    ax.set_xlim([xlims.min(), xlims.max()])

bpAx.set_xticklabels([])  # clear out overlapping xlabels
bpAx.set_yticks([])  # don't need that 1 tick mark
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes and the best way I've seen to handle this can be found [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/24-histogram-with-a-boxplot-on-top-seaborn/).
Copy of code and graph:

```
# Import library and dataset
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
 
# Cut the window in 2 parts
f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})
 
# Add a graph in each part
sns.boxplot(df["sepal_length"], ax=ax_box)
sns.distplot(df["sepal_length"], ax=ax_hist)
 
# Remove x axis name for the boxplot
ax_box.set(xlabel='')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and this worked for me. The image link is here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/preetihemant/preetihemant.github.io/master/images/hist_boxplot.png

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.hist(data,histtype='bar',bins=[values]) 
plt.xlabel('x-label')
plt.ylabel('y-label')
plt.title('Graph title')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.boxplot(values)

plt.show()
```