# How do I overlay a boxplot over my histogram - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I currently have a dataframe called df with 18 columns, and I have plotted a histogram of each to check the distribution shape of each variable using the hist() function in pandas:

```
df.hist(figsize=(30,30))
```

What I now want to do is add a boxplot above each box plot so I can understand at a glance which variables contain outliers.  I want the plot to look as follows:

[image]

I can plot the boxplot using the following code, but it displays all of the boxplots on a single plot:

```
df.boxplot(figsize=(30,30))
```

And I can add a group by, however, this isn't what I require.  I just want each histogram in my df.hist plot to be overlayed with the boxplot derived from the same column of data.  I suspect I could write a funciton to do this, but as the hist function seems quite intuitive, I suspect there is a straighforward way that I'm probably missing.

Comment: Not that I know of. Pandas provides convenience wrappers for commonly used matplotlib functions. What you gain in comfortability, you lose in adaptability. You can modify this answer, though:  [Histogram with Boxplot above in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381330/histogram-with-boxplot-above-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for advice - I can see in the example provided the function is only for a 1-d array, however, this should be pretty straightforward to update using a for loop so it iterates through each of my column.  Thanks again